# Calling `sed` from inside a python program

Tags: python, json, bash, sed

I have the following code snippet in bash which I use for processing a JSON file.I want to do the exactly same functionality in python. Can I call `sed` from python? Or how do I achieve the same thing.

```
for file in /home/Work/ts_parts/*
do
        event=$(cat $file | jq '.Event')
        name="$(basename "$file")"
        if [[ "$event" =~ "aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd" ]]  || [[ "$event" =~ "eeee.ffff.gggg.hhhh" ]]; then
                echo "Coming Here"
                jq ".url = \"$(jq '.Msg' $file | sed 's/.*proxy=\([^&]*\).*/\1/')\"" $file  > ts_parts/out_$name
        else
                jq ".url = null" $file > ts_parts/out_$name
        fi
        rm -f $file
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
import re

s = "abc proxy=123&456"                 # Test string

mat = re.search(r'proxy=([^&]*)', s)
print(mat.group(1))                     # 123
```

This code only does what your sed replacement (extraction) does.  Anything else from the script you'd also have to implement, or call programs directly.

Comment: -how do I add a new key url to the json data and dump it to the file in python?

Comment: @liv2hak you'll want to look into the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module -- `json.load` to load a json into a dictionary from a file, manipulate the dictionary however you want, then `json.dump` to save the modified json.